# Asp.net core MVC model update in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have my model "model":

```
public class model
    {
        /// Tady přidat všechny kolonky v db a jejich vlastnosti pomocí [VLASTNOST]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Data1 { get; set; }
        public string Data2 { get; set; }
        public string Data3 { get; set; }
        public string Data4 { get; set; }
   }
```

Then my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> View(int? id)
        {
            ViewData["Reklamace"] = await _db.model.ToListAsync();
            ViewBag.Id = id ?? 1;
            return View();
        }
```

Then my View:

```
 IEnumerable<model> ReklamaceModel = ViewData["model"] as IEnumerable<model>;
    int Pozice = (int)ViewBag.Id;
    int previous = 1;
    if (Pozice != 1)
    {
        previous = Pozice - 1;
    }
    int next = Pozice + 1;
    int last = ReklamaceModel.Count();
    int first = 1;
    if (next > last)
    {
        next = Pozice;
    }
    if (first > Pozice)
    {
        Pozice = first;
    }
    int IdPozice = 0;
    try
    {
        IdPozice = ReklamaceModel.ElementAt(Pozice).Id;
    }
    catch
    {
        IdPozice = ReklamaceModel.ElementAt(Pozice - 1).Id;
    }
   var MainModel = ReklamaceModel.Where(s => s.Id == IdPozice).First();
```

I then need to use this "MainModel" like data source in `@Html.TextBoxFor()`. I have tried to do these calculations and model manimulations in backend but I need load speed and when I do it in backend my web is like 3 times slower. So I came to the conclusion that I need to somehow set in View my @model to null model and then update it's value. Some idea how to do it??
I have tried `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data1, new { @Value = "3" })`
Why I need this?: Because I am trying to insert data and I have found that `@Html.TextBoxFor` is somehow best for it (using Entity Framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are sending all data? Request is for specific id. Try this in controller:

`ViewData["Reklamace"] = await _db.model.Find(id);`